# react native debugger on android emulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

i create my app via react-native init and run android emulator and i am trying to debug it via react native debugger. i connect my app to the react native debugger but inside Sources tab i cant see my folders like: src, images, etc. i see all files without their folder including all node_modules files. How can i see my src folder and inside it the javascript files?
here is what i am seeing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/678kZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `debugger`. It will stop execution and it will show breakpoint from that line.

```js
willFocusAction = () => {
  debugger;
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  this.wsGetContestList(this.state.defaultPage, false)
}
```